# Before and After mean difference with positive and negative changes

Tags: mean, paired-data

I have a table of data.

Column 1 Before
Column 2 After

In some cases the After values are larger than the Before and vice versa.

If I calculate the difference between each Before/After pair some values are negative some are positive. I then calculate the mean difference and get a small value. Much smaller than I would expect looking at the difference between Before and After values. The problem is the positives and negatives are canceling each other out, it's the mean after all.

So I make a new column and calculate the absolute difference for each Before/After pair. I then calculate the mean difference and get a much more sensible (in my mind) value which is more representative of the actual difference.

Is there a better way I can express the variation between before and after values?

Comment: The standard is using the square of the difference.

Comment: Related:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/best-practice-when-analysing-pre-post-treatment-control-designs